# Present UIImagePickercontroller with slide transition

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiviewanimationtransition, catransformlayer

I have a view with swipe gesture added, when the user right swipes the view i have to show camera with slide transition.I am not sure how to add slide in transition to the UIImagepickercontroller. Can some one tell how to achieve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want is slide transition from right to left? Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412467/dismissmodalviewcontroller-with-transition-left-to-right