# Add Transition effect without using navigationController- IOS

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I want to add a transition effect to my `app` from a `ViewController` to another.

I want use the transition effect that the `Navigation Controller` usually add (sliding effect) but without using the `Navigation Controller`.

What is the simplest and easiest way to achieve that? (I'm using `swift 3`)

EDIT:

My Code Now:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
}

@IBAction func GoToMenu(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //TRANSITION EFFECT
    let nextVCID="010101"
    guard let presentedController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: nextVCID) else { return }

    presentedController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
    self.present(presentedController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate question: I don't want hide a Navigation Controller in all my app for do that!

Comment: I reopened your question. You are correct, that other question was not a duplicate.

Comment: Do you want to transition from one view to another or from one view **controller** to another?

Comment: From a View Controller to another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can present it modaly and set modal transition style you like.

```
    guard let presentedController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: nextVCID) else { return }

    presentedController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
    self.present(presentedController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: nextVCID: Sorry but where I can find the ID of the ViewController? I have the name of the class but got an error with that.

Comment: You have to add it to your storyboard to be able to instantiate it from it. Also you have to set this new view controller your class and id.

Comment: This is the easiest solution for your needs. You should read up on storyboards and adding a unique identifier to a scene.

Comment: Of course when you do not need IBOutlets and similar stuff, which storyboards offer you, you can always do it like that: `let presentedController = NextViewController()` But you will have to add every button,label, etc. programmatically.

Comment: I added the right VCID and I put your code on my button call but when I run the app I see the  default transition (From the BOTTOM to the TOP) instead I'd like to have (From Left to Right) as the Navigation Controller usually add. Check my code in the question please

Comment: You will have to create your own transition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541259/iphone-how-to-do-a-presentmodalviewcontroller-animation-from-left-to-right